# Force hover wait over html element before adding attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a gallery of PNGs. Depending on the number of elements in a list (e.g., myList), I display the same number of PNGs. In this toy example, I'm just using four pictures.

My goal is to have users thoroughly inspect each picture before selecting an image by clicking on it. Currently, the code below allows users to hover over each image in order to enlarge it. The border of the image also turns green to help users keep track of which pictures they've already looked at. I also added a class called "tracker" to check if users have looked at the image.

Critically, however, I'd like to force users to have to hover over an image for at least 500ms before being able to enlarge the image, turn the border green, and add the class "tracker". That way they are forced to carefully inspect each image.

Problem: right now, they can just quickly move their cursor over the images and the "tracker" adds the class and the images turn green. In other words, users can cheat/not carefully look at the images and just quickly highlight every image green.

The code I have below forces users to wait at least 500ms when the window loads, but doesn't force users to wait and hover over *each* image.

I'm guessing the solution will be related to transition-delay but haven't figured out how to implement it yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      /* border: solid 2px black; */
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      /* border: solid 2px black; */
      width: 75px;
    }

    .images {
      width: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: transform 0.5s;
    }

    .images:hover {
      -ms-transform: scale(2.5);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: scale(2.5);
      /* Safari 3-8 */
      transform: scale(2.5);
      outline: 2px solid #CECECE;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    let $buttons = $('<div id="buttonGallery">');
    let myList = ["dog.png", "cat.png", "mouse.png", 'horse.png'];

    var startTime = performance.now()

    myList.map(function(picture) {
      let $button = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('buttons')
        .attr('id', 'button_' + picture)
        .html("<img src='" + picture + "' class='images'></img>")
        .css("border", "10px solid #CECECE")
        .css("margin", "10px")
        .on("mouseenter", function() {
          var check_mouse = performance.now();
          var counter = Math.round(check_mouse - startTime);
          if (counter > 500) {
            console.log(counter)
            $(this).hasClass('tracker');
            $(this).addClass('hovered_on');
            $(this).css("border", "10px solid #529A84");
          } else if (count < 500) {
            return pass
          }
        })
        .on("click", function() {
          console.log("do a thing")
        })
      $buttons.append($button);
    });

    $('body').append($buttons);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Set `startTime` in the mouseenter.  It's unclear if they need to hover all that time or click after that time.  If click, then move your .now() check to click.  If hover, then use a setTimeout - clear the setTimeout on mouseleave

Comment: Off topic: as a user, if I'm presented with 4 images to "inspect", I would not and would not want to point at each one to show I'm "inspecting it" - I would look at all 4 without moving the mouse at all.   If you showed one at a time, then it would be different.

Comment: make research for the term `js hover intent` u will find what you are looking for